# How to move from example.com to app.example.com

Tags: laravel, cloudflare, lamp, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

I have a Laravel app running on AWS LightSail LAMP stack by bitnami. The site is accessible from *example.com*. Now I want to move that app **from** example.com **to** **app**.example.com . The *example.com* will later be used to serve company profile/  product portfolio marketing purposes.

The current codebase is under **/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/** directory, not in any subdirectory.

My queries are:

- How do I achieve the above explained domain structure so that in future i can add more subdomains if necessary?
- Do I need to make any changes in the DNS records?

Answer (score 1):

Bitnami engineer here!

By default, the server is configured to dispatch the contents in the `/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/` directory when accessing it.

Having said that, I usually like to leave that path for the main application (or the main domain in your case) and set up another directory for sub-applications, `/opt/bitnami/projects/PROJECT_NAME` (I'll be using *sub*, which stands for subapp ).

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /opt/bitnami/project/sub/htdocs
# Add the code of your sub site here
$ sudo cat | sudo tee index.html > /dev/null << EOF
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>
EOF
```

In order to add more subdomains you need to create new `VirtualHosts` (in `/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/vhosts/`) that will handle the requests matching those specific subdomains. The stack comes with sample files for `VirtualHosts`, so you only need to copy and tailor them to your needs:

```
$ cd /opt/bitnami/apache/conf/vhosts/
$ sudo cp sample-vhost.conf.disabled sub-vhost.conf
$ sudo cp sample-https-vhost.conf.disabled sub-https-vhost.conf
```

Edit those files to set the `ServerAlias` directive to match your subdomain and you should be ready to go!

```
$ cat sub-vhost.conf
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80 _default_:80>
  ServerAlias sub.myapp.com
...
```

Comment: Following this guideline able to serve content from sub.myapp.com. but the issue now is i am seeing the same content from sub.myapp.com  if accessed from myapp.com.